# How to get taxonomies list by multiple ids with Wordpress REST API?

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming, wordpress-rest-api

I have an issue with taxonomies in REST API,

I know how to get taxonomy, for example **tags**, attributes by its id like this:

```
www.example.com/wp-json/wp/v2/tags/282
```

But what about multiple ids, for example, I have two ids - 282, 283,

can I get list of these tags by one request?
Something like:

```
www.example.com/wp-json/wp/v2/tags/[282,283]
```

Can you help me, please?